# Getting Network error IOException in iReport during connection to MSSQL

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports

I'm getting an error while connecting to a *MSSQL* server in *iReport* designer on *Ubuntu*.
[image: check the error screenshot]

```
JDBC driver: jtds.JDBC
```

Is there anything I've missed?

> Exception
>
> Message:
>      java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
>   Level:
>      SEVERE
>   Stack Trace:
>   Network error IOException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
>       net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.(ConnectionJDBC2.java:410)
>       net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
>       net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
>       com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JDBCConnection.getConnection(JDBCConnection.java:140)
>       com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JDBCConnection.test(JDBCConnection.java:447)

Comment: Could you please paste the `exception` error message?

Comment: do you connect through a proxy?

Comment: @MrsTang, Yes i connect through proxy

Comment: @Atropo, Please check my exception

Comment: Looks like an error from the reply you get from the socks server. Do you have the possibility to try without the proxy server?

Comment: Yes, without proxy it works fine, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, The issue with proxy connection, Without proxy it works fine